# How to get a specific html element

Tags: jquery, html

I need just the image tags within .foo, not all the HTML. I have fiddled around with filter(), children(), find() and I just don't know how to do what I need done. Can someone help?

```js
$modules = 
$('.foo').map(function() {
      return $(this).html();
  }).get().join("<br>");

  alert($modules);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="foo">
    <h5>Text</h5>
    <div class="remove">X</div>
    <img class="image" src="img.png">
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <h5>Text2</h5>
    <div class="remove">X</div>
    <img class="image" src="img2.png">
    <h5>Text3</h5>
    <div class="remove">X</div>
    <img class="image" src="img3.png">
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <h5>Text4</h5>
    <div class="remove">X</div>
    <img class="image" src="img4.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want all the <img> html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.prop()` method to get img tags themeselves as follow:

```
.prop('outerHTML');
```

First get a collection of image tags with `'.foo img'` selector, then take their `outerHTML` property.

Here is a solution

```js
$modules = 
$('.foo img').map(function() {
      return $(this).prop('outerHTML');
  }).get().join("<br>");

  alert($modules);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="foo">
    <h5>Text</h5>
    <div class="remove">X</div>
    <img class="image" src="img.png">
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <h5>Text2</h5>
    <div class="remove">X</div>
    <img class="image" src="img2.png">
    <h5>Text3</h5>
    <div class="remove">X</div>
    <img class="image" src="img3.png">
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <h5>Text4</h5>
    <div class="remove">X</div>
    <img class="image" src="img4.png">
</div>
```

Comment: You're a hero, @Banzay, that's exactly what I needed. I wish I'd asked before I'd banged my head on the desk for hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `img` to your selector:

```
$modules = 
$('.foo img').map(function() {
  return $(this).html();
}).get().join("<br>");

alert($modules);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your logic is that you missed to mention the `img` tag filtering.

In case if you need the elements to do more operations on them you can use the below extraction methodology.

```js
$modules = $('.foo').find('img').map(function() {
      return $(this);
  });

alert($modules.length);

$modules.each(function( index ) {
    alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="foo">
    <h5>Text</h5>
    <div class="remove">X</div>
    <img class="image" src="https://findicons.com/files/icons/861/tweet_my_web/128/single_bird.png">
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <h5>Text2</h5>
    <div class="remove">X</div>
    <img class="image" src="img2.png">
    <h5>Text3</h5>
    <div class="remove">X</div>
    <img class="image" src="img3.png">
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <h5>Text4</h5>
    <div class="remove">X</div>
    <img class="image" src="img4.png">
</div>
```